# Hierarchically sorted MySQL output with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, loops

I'm revising the navigation of my news system and would like to do so using minimal MySQL queries. I've managed to get it all down to one query, but something seems to be wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I wish to achieve is (literally) the following overview of events, hierarchically sorted per year and month, along with the number of events in that month:

```
2012
--04 (3)
--02 (1)
--01 (1)
2011 
--12 (3)
--11 (2)
--10 (3) 
--09 (1)
--07 (1)
--02 (1)
```

I'm very close. My query is as follows:

```
SELECT start_date, date_format(start_date, "%Y") as year, date_format(start_date, "%m") as month FROM event ORDER BY start_date desc
```

Then, my PHP loop is as follows:

```
    $year           = '';
    $year_counter   = 0;
    $month      = '';
    $month_counter  = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if ( $year != $row['year'] ) {
            $year = $row['year'];
            $output .= $year.'<br />';
        }   
        if ( $month == $row['month'] ) {
            $month_counter++;
        } else {
            $month = $row['month'];
            $output .= '--'.$month.' ('.$month_counter.')<br />';
            $month_counter = 1;
        } 
    }
```

Which generates everything perfectly, except for the number of events per month, that seem to be always one line off (you please see the difference with the wanted result above).

```
2012
--04 (1)
--02 (3)
--01 (1)
2011
--12 (1)
--11 (3)
--10 (2)
--09 (3)
--07 (1)
--02 (1)
```

I've been tinkering with this all afternoon without success. I think it's best to leave it to the absolute experts. A hand please?

Comment: what happens if you place the month loop inside the year if expression?

Comment: if I do this, only the first month of each year is displayed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're printing the month_counter before you've updated it for the next month.  Before your while loop, you need to initialize your variables based on the first row retrieved rather than the default values.

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result){
    $year = $row['year'];
    $month = $row['month'];
    $month_counter = 1;  //1 because you've already counted the first article
    // print out the first year
    $output .= $year.'<br />';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result){
        if ( $year != $row['year'] ) {
            $year = $row['year'];
            $output .= $year.'<br />';
        }   
        if ( $month == $row['month'] ) {
            // You've found one more article for this month, so increment the count
            $month_counter++;
        } else {
            // You've hit a new month, so print out the information you collected
            // about the previous month
            $output .= '--'.$month.' ('.$month_counter.')<br />';
            $month = $row['month'];
            $month_counter = 1;
        } 
    }
}
```

The difference between outputting the year and outputting the month, is that you also want to output the count associated with the month, whereas there is no additional information associated with the year. You have to print that before you change to the next month.

Comment: Thank you, but this produces unexpected results... The first month of 2012 (namely 04) is missing...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that you also need to switch $output  with $month=  in the else block.

Comment: Hi, I don't know if I understand correctly, because putting this in the else block causes the script to only show the years. The variable output should contain everything and is returned at the end of the script...

Comment: I think my response to your comment was unclear.  I edited the answer above based on my comment.    I hope this helps.

Comment: Very, very good! This works, but still one little snag. The event of January 2012 is displayed as the first month of year 2011. Also, the very last event, namely February of 2011 is stripped... Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Put the if block that prints the year after the if-else block that prints the month.  That will fix the issue with January.  For the other issue with the last entry not printing, add one more  $output .= '--'.$month.' ('.$month_counter.')<br />'; after the end of the big while block.  Let me know if any of that is unclear.  You should try tracing through the loop in your head or on paper to understand why you're having these problems, though.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I always do try to unravel the logic on paper, but sometimes I get lost in the details. I really appreciate all the time and effort you've put into this. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
$month = $row['month'];
```

is in the wrong place. It sets the $month-variable for a new month, but it has been counting the number for the months before it.

The first time it runs through the while-loop

```
if ( $month == $row['month'] )
```

can never be true, so it goes into the else-statement, displaying the month and the count (which is 1 because you set it to 1 at the top)...

Comment: You should set the $month-variable in the first if-statement ;)

Comment: Thank you, but if I set the month variable in the first if statement (the year statement), then the first month of 2012 (4) is missing. Is could you please provide a little more insight?

Answer (score 0):

I probably made some mistake here, but you could count events per Year-month and group them accordingly.. something like

```
SELECT start_date, date_format(start_date, "%Y") as year, date_format(start_date, "%m") as month, date_format(start_date, "%Y%m") gr, COUNT(id) 
FROM event 
ORDER BY start_date desc 
GROUP BY gr
```